# Can i find the coordinates of items on my desktop?

Tags: automation, rpa, g1ant

There are several items on my desktop such as files and software, I want to know the coordinate of these items or just the coordinate of their centre only in the script so that I can use them later in my script. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: do you want to start scripts which have a shortcut on your desktop?

Comment: No, I want a script through which I can get the coordinates of desktop shortcuts

Comment: And what is next? Let's say, you got alle the infos from the desktop icons.

Comment: I just want to get the mouse position, so that insisted of using "program" command I can directly run the software or open the files if desktop shortcut is already there.

Comment: If you just want to run programs from your desktop, then you do not need the coordinates of those icons. That is why, I asked what you really want to do.

Comment: Actually, it's my curiosity too, whether it is possible or not?

Comment: See here : https://superuser.com/questions/625854/where-does-windows-store-icon-positions

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639486/Save-and-Restore-Icon-Positions-on-Desktop

Comment: @HimaniVarshney possible? Yes, it always was. Useful? No - you don't need the shortcut to know if a program is installed, to execute it, to send context menu verbs to it. If you want to check whether a shortcut exists, you can check that through code or by checking the registry.