# Can software's icon be read by commands of addon image?

Tags: automation, rpa, g1ant

There are some softwares installed in my system such as MATLAB, CATIA, etc. and there is their desktop shortcut too. Is it possible to find the coordinates of these shortcuts using their software icon with the help of image addon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can i find the coordinates of items on my desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535162/can-i-find-the-coordinates-of-items-on-my-desktop)

Comment: Asking the same unclear question twice isn't going to improve it or change the answers. You don't need the coordinates to execute shell commands or verbs like print, open etc, invoke context menu commands, or modify shortcuts. You don't need to check the shortcuts to see if a program is installed. You don't need the *coordinates* to see if a specific shortcut exists or what it contains. All of these things are available through Win32 functions, COM  interfaces, Powershell or even VBScript commands

Comment: I don't want to use shell commands, neither I want to know through the shortcuts whether a particular program is installed. This question doesn't have any similarity with the last question except I am talking about Desktop Icon. If the question is not clear to you, then I can elaborate, basically using addon image I can find out whether some particular image exists on the screen or not and it's coordinate, but icons are not in image format.  So, that's my question is it possible that robot can recognise those icons in some way through Image Addon.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. The desktop *is* the shell. You can't work with icons,commands and verbs without the Shell API. *EVERYTHING* you do will be translated to Shell API calls. That click? It's the `Open` verb. Right click>Print? That's the Print verb. What you see and where is controlled by the shell API. You don't need any kind of robot, what you ask is possible and actually widely done since 1995. In fact, what passes for RPA today is not much better than the old macro recorder applications run on a schedule. Which also goes back to 1995-2000.

Comment: This is still unclear, still the same as the previous question. You won't be able to find any solution until you understand what the icons and desktop are (ie shell), how those things work and how they called programmatically. Why do you care about *images* for example when you can iterate over all shortcuts on the desktop and read the images or paths to them directly? Why use any kind of image recognition when you can just list all resources in an executable (including icons) and determine whether *that's* what's displayed, by the shortcut settings themselves?

Comment: Could it be that a flawed recorder only recorded *screen coordinates* instead of actual Windows actions? In that case, simply moving to a different screen would break the macro, which is why macro recorders *don't* work that way.